# Insert with multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, insert

I am trying to write some code where, inside a for loop, I first push back a vector inside a multidimensional vector, and then insert the same vector from the left in the row below.

However I get a error from the compiler.

This is the part of the code I am referring to.

```
for(int i2=0;i2<pow(2,NG-4)-1;i2+=2){
newTree.push_back(ROW);
newTree.insert(newTree[i2+1].begin(),ROW.at(0),ROW.end()+1);    
}
```

I am trying to add the vector ROW to the multidimensional vector newTree from the right at the line i2. Then I want to insert ROW from the left at line i2+1.

Any idea on how to fix it? Or any better idea on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, if that is your exact code, this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
2^(NG-4)-1
```

That will give you a bitwise XOR with 2 and (NG-4) and then subract 1.  So if NG-4 = 5 (for example), 2^(NG-4) = 7.  I think what you meant for it to do is:

```
pow(2, NG - 4) - 1
```

It sounds like you want `ROW` inserted once, and then it's reverse inserted once?  That being the case, this would work:

```
newTree.push_back(ROW);
vector<whateverTypeYouAreUsing> REVROW(ROW.rbegin((), ROW.rend());
newTree.push_back(REVROW);
```

If you are looking to insert into a vector of vectors in alternating fashion:

```
vector<int> v1 {5, 5, 5, 5};
vector<int> v2 {1, 2};
vector<vector<int>> v3;
for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
{
    vector<int> t;
    if (i % 2)
    {
         copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter<vector<int>>(t));
         t.push_back(v1[i]);
    }
    else
    {
         t.push_back(v1[i]);
         copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter<vector<int>>(t));
    }
    v3.push_back(t);
}
```

You could also do it without the loop, but for clarity I'll leave the loop there.

For a generalized version:

```
class MyTree
{
public:
    void Initialize(const std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            std::vector<int> t(1, v[i]);
            m_Tree.push_back(t);
        }
    }

    void AddVector(const std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tree.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 2)
            {
                std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::front_inserter<deque<int>>(m_Tree));
            }
            else
            {
                std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter<deque<int>>(m_Tree));
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::deque<int>> m_Tree;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction for the power of 2.

What I want to do afterwards is exactly what I´ve written. I want to add row from the right and then add it in the next line from the left.

You can forget about the reversing part for now. (Thanks for the correction on that part as well btw. )

Comment: The whole "add a line from the right ... from the left" is what I'm not understanding.  What is it you are trying to do there?

Comment: Let's say that my bidimensional vector newTree is for the moment just a column vector filled with numbers, e.g. 
    5
    5
    5
    5
Now I want to add a vector ROW=(1,2) first from the right and then from the left..to obtain:
    125
    512
    125
    512

Comment: So you have 2 vectors, and you want to merge them into 1 vector by concatenating the values of one onto the other for every other value?  Assuming your end result is a vector of vectors, you would just need to alternate your insertions.  I'll add an example showing that.

Comment: Unfortunately it's more complicated than that.
I have more than 2 vectors in general. So I need to be able to add the new vectors at the beginning and at the end (alternating the two ways) to the row vectors in newTree.

Comment: You would use the same basic strategy.  I'll show you a generalized version as well.

Comment: Note that since you need to do inserts to the front as well, it is more efficient to use a vector of deques instead of a vector of vectors.

Comment: I get a "no matching function for call" for front_inserter and back_inserter.

Comment: Did you include `<iterator>`?

Comment: Yes I did. Anyway, I solved that problem...now I have a new one that I wrote in the reply below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "no matching function for call" problem.

Now I get this error that I don't understand at all.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_iterator.h: In member function 'std::front_insert_iterator<_Container>& std::front_insert_iterator<_Container>::operator=(typename _Container::const_reference) [with _Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]':
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:342:   instantiated from 'static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = int*, _OI = std::front_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]'
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:396:   instantiated from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false, _II = int*, _OI = std::front_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]'
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:435:   instantiated from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false, _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _OI = std::front_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]'
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:466:   instantiated from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _OI = std::front_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]'
```

My new code is:

```
vector<int> PI_comb(vector<int> Tree, vector<int> legs, int pi){

vector<int> rooted(NG-1);
for(int i=0;i<NG-1;i++)rooted.at(i)=Tree.at(i);
vector< vector<int> > L;
L.resize(legs.size());
for(int azz=0;azz<legs.size();azz++)L[azz].resize(legs.at(azz));
for(int rho=0;rho<legs.size();rho++){
for(int i=0;i<legs[rho];i++)L[rho][i]=rooted.at(i);
}

vector< vector<int> > newTree/*(std::pow(2,NG-3),vector<int>(NG-1))*/;
for(int cc=0;cc<legs.size();cc++){
if(legs.at(cc)==2){
vector<int> ROW(legs.at(cc));
for(int argh=0;argh<legs.at(cc);argh++)ROW.at(argh)=L[cc][argh];
vector<int> REVROW(ROW.rbegin(), ROW.rend());
for(int i2=0;i2<(std::pow(2,NG-4)-1);i2++){
    if (i2%2==0)
            {
    if (i2==0||i2==4||i2==8)
                std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
        else 
        std::copy(REVROW.begin(),REVROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            }
        else
            {
    if (i2==1||i2==5||i2==9)    
                /*LINE 156*/std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
        else
                std::copy(REVROW.begin(),REVROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            }

}
for(int i2=std::pow(2,NG-4);i2<(std::pow(2,NG-3)-1);i2+=2){
    if(cc>0&&legs.at(cc-1)==2){
        if (i2%2==0)
                {
            if (i2==0||i2==4||i2==8)
                    std::copy(REVROW.begin(),REVROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            else 
            std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
                }
                else
                {
            if (i2==1||i2==5||i2==9)    
                    std::copy(REVROW.begin(),REVROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            else
                    std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
                }


    }
    else{
        if (i2%2==0)
                {
            if (i2==0||i2==4||i2==8)
                    std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            else 
            std::copy(REVROW.begin(),REVROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
                }
                else
                {
            if (i2==1||i2==5||i2==9)    
                    std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
        else
                    std::copy(REVROW.begin(),REVROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
                }
    }

}
}
else if(legs.at(cc)==1){
vector<int> ROW(legs.at(cc));
for(int argh=0;argh<legs.at(cc);argh++)ROW.at(argh)=L[cc][argh];
if(cc!=legs.size()-1){
for(int i2=0;i2<(std::pow(2,NG-3)-1);i2+=2){
if (i2%2==0)
            {
                std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            }
else
            {
                std::copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),std::front_inserter<vector<int> >(newTree.at(i2)));
            }
}
}
else if(cc==legs.size()-1){
for(int i2=0;i2<std::pow(2,NG-3);i2++)newTree.push_back(ROW);
}
}
}

//RETURN
if(pi<=std::pow(2,NG-3)){
for(int ag=0;ag<NG-1;ag++)
Tree.at(ag)=newTree[pi][ag];
}
else if(pi>std::pow(2,NG-3)){
vector<int> row(NG-1);
for(int a=0;a<NG-1;a++)row.at(a)=newTree[pi-std::pow(2,NG-3)][a];
vector<int> REVrow(row.rbegin(), row.rend());
for(int a=0;a<NG-1;a++)Tree.at(a)=REVrow.at(a);
}

return(Tree);

}
```

This is just a function that basically changes the order of the elements inside the vector Tree according to some special pattern.
I think that now it would do what I want it to do..but I don't understand those errors.

Ok, I solved it. vector doesn't have front_inserter defined.

I had to use:

```
copy(ROW.begin(),ROW.end(),inserter(newTree[i2],newTree[i2].begin()));
```

Comment: One last line in the compiler output says:

Final.cpp:156:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_iterator.h:497: error: 'class std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' has no member named 'push_front'

I modified my answer so that you can see line 156.

Comment: That is correct.  If you want the `push_front` capability, you would need to switch to using a `std::deque`.  `std::vector` has a `push_back` method, which allows you to use a `std::back_inserter` iterator.